# WIA - Carregar os dispositivos da rede

Tags: c#

Estou escrevendo um código em C# e uso WIA para realizar tarefas de escaneamento. Entretanto, estou tendo problemas em capturar os dispositivos que estão compartilhados na rede. Meu código captura todos os dispositivos que estão conectados direto na máquina.

```
public static List<string> GetDevices() {
    List<string> devices = new List<string>();
    WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
    foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos) {
       devices.Add(info.DeviceID);
    }
    return devices;
}
```

Alguem sabe como faço para ler os dispositivos que estão compartilhados na rede?

Comment: Você quer dizer aqules dispositivos que aparece em "Meus Locais de Rede" (esqueci o nome atual!)?

Comment: Acredito que isso possa te ajudar: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths